# Perl / xargs terrible performance with xargs -n1/-i

Tags: perl, xargs

I have a little perl one-liner I wrote:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -i perl -ne 'if (/\+\+\S*[cC]ursor\S*/ && !/[!=]=\s*DB_NULL_CURSOR/) {print "$ARGV:$.\n $_\n";}' {}
```

In the directory I'm running this, the `find` portion returns 5802 results.

Now, I understand `xargs -i` (or `-n1`) is going to have a performance impact, but with `-i`:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -print0 2> /dev/null  0.33s user 1.12s system 0% cpu 3:12.57 total
xargs -0 -i perl -ne  {}  4.12s user 32.80s system 16% cpu 3:42.22 total
```

And without:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -print0 2> /dev/null  0.27s user 1.22s system 95% cpu 1.556 total
xargs -0 perl -ne   0.62s user 0.69s system 61% cpu 2.117 total
```

Minutes vs. a couple seconds (order of testing confirmed not to matter).  The actual perl results are identical other than the line numbers which are obviously incorrect in the second instance.

Behavior is identical in Cygwin/bash/perl5v26, and WSL Ubuntu 16.04/zsh/perl5v22.  File system is NTFS in both cases.  But...I'm kind of assuming the little one-liner I wrote must have some sort of bug in it and that stuff is irrelevant?

EDIT:  It occurred to me that disabling sitecustomize.pl at startup with `-f` --an option I'd vaguely remembered seeing with `perl --help`--might help.  It did not.  Also, I'm aware that the performance impact of `-i` is going to be *significant* due to perl compiling the regex.  This still seems out of control.

Comment: You don't need either xargs or parallel, you just need to pipe directly to perl, it will loop over your filenames and print them if they fit your regex rules.

Comment: Or even `find ... -exec perl -ne '...' {} +` to avoid the pipe, too.

Comment: @xxfelixxx without xargs, you have to open the files in perl, and because of  `-print0` you won't get them line by line. Maybe it's better to simply use a perl script with [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find)

Comment: So it takes 55x longer, but you spawn between 100x and 8000x more `perl` interpreters...

Comment: @tripleee, While you can avoid xargs by using you use `-exec` instead of `-print0`, `-exec ;` should perform similarly to `xargs -n 1` (and `-exec +` should perform similary to `xargs` without `-n 1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my fundamental misunderstanding was an assumption that the max command line length would be something in the 2000 range.  So I was assuming a perl instance for every 20 files or so (being about 120 characters each).  This was incredibly incorrect.

`getconf ARG_MAX` shows you the actual acceptable length.  In my case:

> 2097152

So, I'm looking at 1 perl instance vs. 5802 instances.  The only perl solution I can think of would be to remove `-n` and implement the loop by hand, explicitly closing each file.

Better solutions, I think, are awk:

```
 find . -name '*.cpp' 2>/dev/null -print0 | xargs -0 awk '{if (/\+\+\S*[cC]ursor\S*/ && !/[!=]=\s*DB_NULL_CURSOR/) {print FILENAME ":" FNR "  " $0}}'
```

or grep:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' 2>/dev/null -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nE '\+\+\S*[cC]ursor\S*' | grep -v '[!=]=\s*DB_NULL_CURSOR'
```

Both of which execute in the 2 or 3 second range.

Answer (score 1):

xargs will invoke a new process for every line it processes, so in your case it will be spinning up perl 5802 times and doing this in series

You could try in [parallel](http://offbytwo.com/2011/06/26/things-you-didnt-know-about-xargs.html)

> You might be using xargs to invoke a compute intensive command for
>   every line of input. Wouldn’t it be nice if xargs allowed you to take
>   advantage of the multiple cores in your machine? That’s what -P is
>   for. It allows xargs to invoke the specified command multiple times in
>   parallel. You might use this for example to run multiple ffmpeg
>   encodes in parallel. However I’m just going to show you yet another
>   contrived example.

Or on the other hand, you could use [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) which is much lighter to spin up

Comment: Yeah, I've used `-P8` before, and it speeds up things quite a lot.  sed I'm not really familiar with beyond simple single regex commands.  I think doing the line reading loop manually in perl or using awk are both good options